# Mod_Python requires Python Handler for every file?

Tags: python, mod-python

With **mod_python** I am wondering why I have to create a **PythonHandler** in order to get a URL to parse Python code. If you see below, if I do not have a file called jrpython.py it will not work.

Is there a way to make **all of my .py** files just run without adding to this everytime?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot /var/www/vhost/testsite.com
   ServerName www.testsite.com

  <Directory "/var/www/vhost/testsite.com">
        AddHandler mod_python .py
        PythonHandler jrpython
        PythonDebug On
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow From All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: [Why are you using mod_python?](http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2010/06/modpython-project-is-now-officially.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can have mod_python run your .py files without having to name them all. You still need to specify a PythonHandler, but that can be the [Publisher handler](http://www.modpython.org/live/current/doc-html/hand-pub.html).